# (Discrete Math) I'm having a really hard time with this problem as I'm new to the subject. Any help is appreciated.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Using the pigeonhole principle, prove that among any n+ 1 integers you can find two integers so that their difference is divisible by n.  You will want the “holes” to be the remainder when you divide a value by n.

Comment: you can look at: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/958636/prove-that-there-exist-two-integers-such-that-i-j-is-divisible-by-n

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: So $n+1$ pigeons and $n$ holes. Sounds good.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the set $A$ with $3$ numbers. The possible differences are $3$.

If $A$ contains all even or all odd, the differences are all even. If it contains 1 even and two odd or if it contains 1 odd and two even 1 difference is even.

A similar claim can be made if $A$ contains $4$ numbers and the possible differences are $6$. The original $4$ numbers can give a remainder of $0,1,2$ when divided by $3$. Differences contain at least $1$ case when the remainder is $0$, because $A$ contains $6$ elements.

If $A$ has $n+1$ numbers, the possible pairs are $d=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$.

The possible differences are $d$ as well.

The elements in $A$ can have remainders $0,1,2,\ldots,n-1$ when divided by $n$ and when subtracting there is at least $1$ who has remainder $0$, that means that is divisible by $n$.

Hope this is clear.